# soCapturar datos de una fila con JQuery - Ajax - Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código que muestra sin ningun problema una tabla de registros generada desde un array json.

```
$.each(query, function (name, value) {
    fileTable +="<tr><td width='10%'><input type='text' name='fechaAsignacion' id='fechaAsignacion' value='"+value.fecha_asignacion+"' class='form-control' placeholder='01/01/2000'></td>"

    fileTable +="<td width='30%'><select name='nuevoEstatus' id='nuevoEstatus' class='form-control select2'>";
    @foreach($estatus as $estatu)
        fileTable +="<option value='{{$estatu->id}}'>{{$estatu->nombre}}</option>"
    @endforeach
    fileTable = fileTable + "</select></td>"

    fileTable +="<td width='50%'><input type='hidden' value='"+value.id+"' name='idEstatus'><textarea name='obs' id='obs' class='form-control'>"+value.observaciones+"</textarea></td>"

    fileTable +="<td width='10%'><a class='btn btn-sm btn-warning' onClick='editarEstatus();'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a> <a class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' onClick='eliminarEstatus();'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a></td></tr>
});
```

Ahora bien, el caso está al momento de capturar la información de cada fila, para editarla, siempre me envia el primer registro, independientemente de que este seleccionando el 5, 6, 20, 28, 50...

En la función `editarUsuario()`, capturo los datos de la fila d la siguiente forma:

```
`idEstatus= $("#idEstatus").val();
 nuevoEstatus = $("#nuevoEstatus").val();
 fechaAsignacion = $("#fechaAsignacion").val();
 obs = $("#obs").val();`
```

Tabla solo en html

```
<table class='table table-condensed' id='tEstatus'>
<thead class='alert alert-info'>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col'>#</th>
        <th scope='col'>Asignación</th>
        <th scope='col'>Observaciones</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope='row'>1</th>"
            <td width='10%'>
                <input type='text' name='fechaAsignacion' value='"+value.fecha_asignacion+"' class='form-control' placeholder='01/01/2000'>
            </td>"
            <td width='50%'>
                <input type='hidden' value='"+value.id+"' name='idEstatus'>
                <textarea name='obs' class='form-control'>"+value.observaciones+"</textarea>
            </td>"
            <td>
                <input type='button' id='editar' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning' value='Editar'>
            </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

"

Alguna sugerencia o cual sería la mejor alternativa para resolver mi duda. Por favor!!!

Comment: A primera vista veo que todos tus <td> generados tendrán ID repartidos, puedes poner el HTML para ver como se genera. como seleccionas cada registro?

Comment: Ya agregué el gragmento de la función que recibe los datos que envio de la fila, mediant la funcion editarUsuario()

Comment: el problema es que estas solicitando datos mediante un `ID` y todos los registros de la tabla generada tienen el mismo `ID` por eso siempre te trae el primer registro, te recomiendo que guardes información en forma de `data-fechaAsig = value.fecha_asignacion` y al momento de seleccionar un registro obtengas su valor

Comment: Trabajandolo de esa manera, igual me siguen tomando la primera linea.

Answer (score 1):

Iintenta esto:

```js
$(".editar").click((e) => {

  const fila = $(e.target).parents("tr");
  let fechaAsignacion = fila.find(".fechaAsignacion").val();
  let asignacion = fila.find(".idEstatus").val();
  let obs = fila.find(".obs").val();
  alert("fechaAsignacion = "+fechaAsignacion+" asignacion = "+asignacion+" obs = "+obs)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class='table table-condensed' id='tEstatus'>
  <thead class='alert alert-info'>
    <tr>
      <th scope='col'>#</th>
      <th scope='col'>Asignación</th>
      <th scope='col'>Observaciones</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>1</th>
      <td width='10%'>
        <input type='text' name='fechaAsignacion' value='20/09/2018' class='form-control fechaAsignacion' placeholder='01/01/2000'>
      </td> 
      <td width='50%'>
        <input type='hidden' value='1' name='idEstatus' class="idEstatus">
        <textarea name='obs' class='form-control obs'>observaciones</textarea>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <input type='button' id='editar' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning editar' value='Editar'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope='row'>2</th>
      <td width='10%'>
        <input type='text' name='fechaAsignacion' value='21/09/2018' class='form-control fechaAsignacion' placeholder='01/01/2000'>
      </td> 
      <td width='50%'>
        <input type='hidden' value='2' name='idEstatus' class="idEstatus">
        <textarea name='obs' class='form-control obs'>observaciones2</textarea>
      </td> 
      <td>
        <input type='button' id='editar' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning editar' value='Editar'>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hice una pequeña tabla con 3 columnas y en cada una de ellas el botón para obtener los datos, en el js podrás ver como obtiene el valor correspondiente a su fila, allí obtengo valores de texto y de inputs, espero te sirva y te puedas guiar.

Comment: Saludos, muy interesante tu respuesta, la probé y captura el id de la fila sin ningun problema, pero ya los demas valores, no los captura. Te anexo el codigo de captura. 
`$("#tEstatusProfesor").on("click", "#editar", (e) => { 
    const fila = $(e.target).parents("tr");
    let id = fila.find("th:first").text();
    let idE = fila.find(".fechaAsignacion").val();
    let nuevoE = fila.find(".nuevoEstatus").val();
    alert("id = "+id+" Nombre = "+idE+" Apellido = "+nuevoE)
});`

Comment: me puedes mandar o especificar un html dek codigo que estas haciendo? es para emular tu tabla, si puedes colocalo en tu pregunta osea sin el php solo un html del resultado del html

Comment: Ya añadí la tabla..

Comment: Listo ya lo modifique segun tu html, revisalo